# Error when using Docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml mynetwork

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

Project structure 
[image]

Here is my .yaml

```yaml
version: "3.3"
services:
  database:
    image: mysql:8
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: ${mysql_user}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${mysql_password}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${mysql_root_password}
    ports:
      - "6033:3306"
    networks:
      - ${network_name}
    volumes:
      - dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
      - "./.scripts/schema.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/1.sql"
      - "./.scripts/data.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2.sql"
    secrets:
      - mysql_user
      - mysql_password
      - mysql_root_password
      - container_name
      - network_name

secrets:
  mysql_user:
    file: /run/secrets/mysql_user
  mysql_password:
    file: /run/secrets/mysql_password
  mysql_root_password:
    file: /run/secrets/mysql_root_password
  network_name:
    file: /run/secrets/network_name

networks:
  ${network_name}:
    driver: bridge
```

Here is my script

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Leave current swarm
docker swarm leave --force

# Initialize the host as a Swarm manager
docker swarm init

# Create the secrets
echo "server_user" | docker secret create mysql_user -
echo "server_password" | docker secret create mysql_password -
echo "a1128f69-e6f7-4e93-a2df-3d4db6030abc" | docker secret create mysql_root_password -
echo "template_network" | docker secret create network_name -

# Deploy the stack using the secrets
docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yaml mynetwork
```

Here is the error

```
Node left the swarm.
Swarm initialized: current node (y46rjvlu57bibyhgwk7nthykw) is now a manager.

To add a worker to this swarm, run the following command:

    docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-161prfq442ha035laq1plnv1o2qfqs026dmg6aslpd4kao7o0i-bnwc5zxiwt3ctmfbxfoszbick 192.168.65.3:2377

To add a manager to this swarm, run 'docker swarm join-token manager' and follow the instructions.

l3nrkqhy7ygtrb05x7c5rvavu
xrhp70n50waaas1hqha8fk2j2
wj1y8runsi8vydpzc09hp9bmp
u5b6suutp7tkt4lqd5i90bgif
Creating network mynetwork_
failed to create network mynetwork_: Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = InvalidArgument desc = name must be valid as a DNS name component
```

I do not get the error when I don't use docker secrets for the variables, so I'm wondering if that is something to do with it.

I have tried restarting / clearing / destroying all the containers / networks / services / images in Docker too.

Any help or tips for improvement are also welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the two `networks:` blocks.

The actual problem here is the top-level `networks:`.  This is outside the context of any particular service, so where you're getting a `network_name` secret within the `database` service, that doesn't happen at the top level.  That means Compose tries to expand the environment variable `network_name` as the network name, but it's empty.

(In Swarm mode you may not want `bridge` networking either.)

If you remove the `networks:` blocks then Compose will create a network named `default` and attach the container(s) to it.  If you do need some non-standard settings then it's possible to configure the `default` network, but keeping the `default` name and still attaching containers to it by default.  More details are in [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.

Comment: Wonderful. One more issue it seems to not be finding the secrets
- open /run/secrets/mysql_root_password: no such file or directory